# open website in app when admob ad click

Tags: android, webview, admob

I just want to make an make that open ad in my app.
Features:
When interstitial ad show and user clicks on ad then don't show pop up dialog containing browsers to open URL, instead URL must open in same app.

Same must do when banner ad click.

I know i want to use webview but how to open ad click URL in that webview.

If anyone knows how to implement this code then help me.

Comment: you want that link is not open in browser only open in the same app am I Right?

Comment: yeah, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Afaik, this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(_URL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

try with this

Comment: It only loads given url in webview, When ad is clicked then we don't have url of that ad. How can we call this function with url?